# Ordenamiento en cxGridDBBandedTableView

Tags: delphi, gridview, component

Me encuentro trabajando con Delphi XE7, y estoy utilizando el componente cxGridBandedTableBackgroundDBBandedTableView que está ligado a una tabla de memoria, al momento de que muestro los valores este componente tiene la posibilidad de ordenarlos de manera ascendente/descendente con tan solo darle clic a la columna, el problema que tengo es que cuando yo ordeno la columna de manera descendente y abro el detalle del registro y doy clic en siguiente registro al que se mueve pareciera que es el anterior en lugar del siguiente, esto debido a que estoy navegando sobre la tabla de memoria y al momento de que reordene los datos en el grid esto no afecto la tabla, quisiera saber si es de su conocimiento alguna propiedad que pudiera utilizar para que al momento de que cambie el ordenamiento en el grid también se afecte la tabla de memoria?

Nota: Anteriormente tenía el problema con el filtrado, debido a que a pesar de tener un filtro en el grid, al entrar al detalle siempre se me mostraban todos los datos de la tabla de memoria, sin importar que hubiese un filtro, investigando se encontró que al aplicar la propiedad AutoDataSetFilter en True, se solventaba este error, y así fue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No olvides que un solo dataset puede estar ligado a muchos controles visuales. De esto se desprende que no hay ningún método o propiedad que automáticamente ordene los datos del dataset según el orden visual que haya en una grilla.

Si imaginas el caso general, qué pasaría si un solo dataset está asociado a dos grillas que el usuario decide ordenar de manera diferente.

Dicho esto, cuando trabajas con los componentes de DevExpress y quieres navegar por los datos en el mismo orden que el usuario ha seleccionado en una vista particular, puedes utilizar la información del controlador de datos de la vista para moverte por el dataset.

Yo lo he hecho, por ejemplo, con un `TClientDataSet` que está ligado a un `TcxGridDBTableView`, pero la idea es general y creo que puedes aplicarla en tu caso utilizando las propiedades `FilteredRecordCount` y `FilteredRecordIndex` del controlador de datos de la vista.

En el ejemplo a continuación, simplemente voy dejando el valor del campo 'Nombre' del dataset en un string list en el mismo orden que tiene la vista, de la siguiente forma:

```
var
  Nombres: TStringList;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Nombres := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for I := 0 to GridView.DataController.FilteredRecordCount - 1 do
    begin
      cdsConsulta.RecNo := GridView.DataController.FilteredRecordIndex[I] + 1;
      Nombres.Add(cdsConsulta.FieldByName('Nombre').AsString);
    end;
    ShowMessage('Los nombres de la grilla en orden son: '#13 + Nombres.Text);
  finally
    Nombres.Free;
  end;
end;
```

`cdsConsulta` es el `TClientDataSet` que contiene los datos y `GridView` es la vista del `cxGrid` que el usuario ha ordenado en tiempo de ejecución, como he dicho antes, es una `TcxGridDBTableView`, pero puedes lograrse con cualquier vista que utilice un `DataController`, es decir, con cualquier vista asociada a datos.

OJO: Me estoy valiendo de que el ClientDataSet tiene la propiedad `RecNo` que permite hacer activo un registro por su número dentro del conjunto de datos. Es probable que con el dataset que utilizas en particular haya que hacer algo diferente para seleccionar el registro apropiado. Esa adaptación queda en tus manos.